# Shiny: Linking to my shared images and css files across apps

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, how can I link to an image or a css file that is not in the www folder of the app?

The situation is that I have several apps that share common code, but need to be treated as distinct apps. At the same time I want them to be styled similarly and therefore I want to link to images and css files that are not specific for the app.

The only way I know of linking to images and css files is to place them inside a folder called www in the app directory. But that means that each app will need a copy of the files, because each app has its own www folder.

When running an app I've noticed that Shiny itself links to files in a subfolder called shared/ but I have not yet found where that folder is located. Can I put my custom files there too?

Symlinking from the www folder to a common place comes to mind, but I'd rather not to have to do that. I'm also aware that I can include css styles inline in the html, but that's another thing I want to avoid.

Comment: How are you deploying? You can use full URLs to link to images and CSS files. You'd have to hard-code the same path for all apps. Not sure this is problem is really specific to Shiny in anyway in how you described it. How would you share any data across different websites.

Comment: Using Shiny Server, and it also has to work during development when launched by R studio. This is not a conventional web server and I don't know how to specify things like document root and aliases. The files must be under the same domain, as I just realised I also want to deploy common javascript files.

Comment: I think you cannot... The only way to access files from disk is within the www folder.

Comment: @Stophface, seems it's easy to miss, but there actually is a function that can do that, see my answer below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching I finally ran into [`addResourcePath`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/addResourcePath.html).

It worked like a charm when added before the shinyApp call.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how this worked for you?  I tried doing this for a folder where I have a common site logo.  I don't get an error when I run the addResourcePath function using prefix='www', but my Shiny app does not pick up the file I want it to use.